# How to end a for loop without a comma? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

i was about to save each number from one cell using for loop here is my code:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In xmlnode
                    Dim X As String
                    Dim Y As String
                    Dim Z As String
                    X = node.SelectSingleNode("X").InnerText
                    Y = node.SelectSingleNode("Y").InnerText
                    Z = node.SelectSingleNode("Z").InnerText

                    Dim noOfPts As Integer = 0  'number of data points in data
                    For i As Double = 0 To noOfPts
                        result = X + ","
                        result2 = Y + ","

                    Next
      Next
```

the thing is i'm going to end the loop without saving the comma. Instead of this "1,2,3,4,5," it should be like this "1,2,3,4,5" remove the comma from the end of the loop.

Comment: use string.join.

Comment: Code sample is unclear, from where `result` and `result2` are coming? We assign new value to it on every iteration? Question is clear and answer for that would be `String.Join` which already suggested by few people here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `StringBuilder` you can simplify the loop by removing `if` statements and make more efficient in most of the cases (especially when you building a string in the loop).

```
Dim xBuilder AS New StringBuilder()
Dim yBuilder As New StringBuilder()
Dim delimiter As String = ", "

For Each node As XmlNode In xmlnode
    Dim X As String = node.SelectSingleNode("X").InnerText
    Dim Y As String = node.SelectSingleNode("Y").InnerText
    Dim Z As String = node.SelectSingleNode("Z").InnerText

    For i As Integer = 0 To noOfPts
        xBuilder.Append(X).Append(delimiter)           
        yBuilder.Append(Y).Append(delimiter)
    Next
Next

' use Math.Max to prevent exception if builder is empty
xBuilder.Length = Math.Max(xBuilder.Length - delimiter.Length, 0)
yBuilder.Length = Math.Max(yBuilder.Length - delimiter.Length, 0)

Dim resultX As String = xBuilder.ToString() ' 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Dim resultY As String = yBuilder.ToString()
```

We are removing last "redundant" delimiter by "cutting" stringbuilder's length by length of delimiter.

For using `String.Join` you need to create a collection of values first

```
Dim xValues AS New List<string>()
Dim yValues As New List<string>()

For Each node As XmlNode In xmlnode
    Dim X As String = node.SelectSingleNode("X").InnerText
    Dim Y As String = node.SelectSingleNode("Y").InnerText
    Dim Z As String = node.SelectSingleNode("Z").InnerText

    For i As Integer = 0 To noOfPts
        xValues.Add(X)
        xValues.Add(Y)
    Next
Next

Dim resultX As String = String.Join(", ", xValues) ' 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Dim resultY As String = String.Join(", ", yValues)
```

Comment: Would appreciate to hear a reason for downvote. Will be glad to fix or remove answer if it is wrong

Comment: This answer contains two acceptable approaches from readability and efficiency point of view. I would suggest to go with `String.Join` option which hash clear and comprehensible steps: 1.Gather information, 2. Build output based on that information.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it this way:

```
For i As Double = 0 To noOfPts
    If result <> "" Then result &= ", "
    result &= X

    If result2 <> "" Then result2 &= ", "
    result2 &= Y
Next
```

Have fun!

Comment: 1. `If Then` is poor approach from readability point of view. 2. Concatenating string with `&` operator will create a copy of original and appending value, in the loop it will increase memory consumption in geometric progression on every iteration. Right tool for the job would be `StringBuilder`.

Comment: thank you for the tip i already upvote this one but nothing happen

Comment: @ナンダルケジー Don't worry about it, it's probably just because your reputation is low. I'm just glad you're progressing. Take care!